# MySQL query to select groups containing at least a certain number of elements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+-------------------+
| Id | G_id | E_id  |
+-------------------+
| 1  |   1  |   1   |
---------------------
| 2  |   1  |   2   |
---------------------
| 3  |   2  |   1   |
---------------------
| 4  |   2  |   3   |
---------------------
| 5  |   3  |   1   |
---------------------
| 6  |   3  |   2   |
---------------------
| 7  |   3  |   3   |
+-------------------+
```

where G_id is a group's id contaning several elements identified by their E_id. For exemple, group 1 is made of elements 1 and 2, group 2 of elements 1 and 3 and group 3 of elements 1, 2 and 3.

I want to make a query over this table so that it returns all groups that contain at least elements 1 and 3, ie groups 2 and 3. Thanks !

Comment: Incidentally, given that `(G_id,E_id)` appears to be UNIQUE, Id would appear to serve no purpose in this table.

Comment: Indeed, the Id column seems useless but is left in case any other solution involves this column.

Comment: There won't be one

Comment: (Actually, ironically enough, the answer given assumes an id column. Otherwise the DISTINCT would be superfluous ;-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `Group By` and `Having` clause

```
select G_id 
from yourtable 
where E_id in (1,3)
group by G_id 
having count(distinct E_id) = 2
```

Update:

```
select G_id 
from yourtable 
group by G_id 
having count(case when E_id = 1 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when E_id = 3 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(distinct E_id) = 3
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to use your query to retrieve all groups of three elements made up of at least elements 1 and 3 by replacing `having count(distinct E_id) = 2` by `having count(distinct E_id) = 3`. Unfortunately this does not work because in `where E_id in (1,3)` array (1,3) is of lower dimension than three. Any idea ?

Comment: This answer is very satisfying as the dimensions of the elements are explicitely stated in the query and can be easily used for tables of higher dimensions.